# ActiveMQ redelivery at application level

Tags: activemq-classic

I use ActiveMQ as a job dispatcher. Which means one master sends job messages to ActiveMQ, and  multiple slaves grab job messages from ActiveMQ and process them. When slaves finish one job, they send a message with job_id back to ActiveMQ.

However, slaves are unreliable. If one slave doesn't respond before a period of time, we can assume the slave is down, and try redeliver the sent job message.

Are there any good ideas to realize this re-delivery?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a consumer handles redelivery so that it can maintain message order while a message appears as inflight on the broker.  This means that redelivery is limited to a single consumer unless that consumer terminates. In this way the broker is unaware of redelivery.

In ActiveMQ v5.7+ you have the option of using broker side redelivery, it is possible to have the broker redeliver a message after a delay using a resend. This is implemented by a broker plugin that handles dead letter processing by redelivery via the scheduler. This is useful when total message order is not important and where through put and load distribution among consumers is. With broker redelivery, messages that fail delivery to a given consumer can get immediately re-dispatched.

See the ActiveMQ [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) for an example of setting this up in the configuration file.